# Request body of Ajax Post request is intermittently missing for spring boot proxy controller via Chrome and Edge browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I am facing weird intermittent issue in Chrome and Edge with my web application while making simple ajax post request on button click. Ajax request lands on spring boot proxy controller of my application, which further uses RestTemplate to send request to thrid party server. I tested same over mozila browser couple of time and didn't face issue even once. Hence I am assuming this weird issue is something related to browser not the code base. Has anyone experience same ?

**Till now Findings:** While debugging I have found that my proxy contoller is recieving blank request body and subsequetly third party server is thowing error which is expected as request body is not passed. However while inspecting my ajax call in chrome browser devtool I could see that request payload has request body. But when I inspect request body parameter in my controller is coming as blank. So why request body is getting missed intermittenly between browser and controller ?

Ajax request :

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: webApiPath + '/search',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            beforeSend: authentication.beforeSend,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(requestObj),
        })
```

My springboot proxy controller :

```
@RequestMapping("/**")
public @ResponseBody JsonResponse proxy(
    @RequestBody(required = false) String body,
    HttpMethod method, HttpServletRequest request) 
    throws URISyntaxException 
{
    
  // Do further stuff if body is not blank
   RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
   ResponseEntity<Object> original = template.exchange(
            url, method, httpEntity, Object.class);
        
   response.setSuccess(original.getBody());
   
 }
```

Spring boot version : release 2.2.5

jquery version : v3.2.1

Java version : 1.8

Chrome version : Version 98.0.4758.82 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: It seems that these browsers with problems are based on chromium, you can try to report the issue through this link: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: I have a similar issue in Firefox 109, where I am sending an ajax request on form submit while preventing the default post request. I have tried manually sending the request, all fine, but as soon as it is in a eventListener, it did not send any body.

Answer (score 0):

The tomcat version which comes along with Spring boot 2.2.5 Release version was 9.0.31. Which was updated to 9.0.33 to fix my problem.